# Why is time.time() result decreases to 50.85 seconds?

Tags: python, linux, time, measure

I used the difference between the two time.time() calls to measure the time that my app takes to complete a network request. App is running at Debian server. The problem is that periodically I get a negative difference between these values, as if time is going backwards.

I wrote a simple example:

```
import time

while True:
    print("OK")
    start_time = time.time()
    time.sleep(0.01)
    end_time = time.time()
    diff = end_time - start_time
    if diff < 0:
        print(start_time)
        print(end_time)
        print(diff)
        break
```

and this is output (this is repeatable and takes only few seconds to get decreasing time):

```
...
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
OK
1558957392.940343
1558957342.089879
-50.8504638671875
```

In my Mac there are no such problems with this code. Now I switched to `time.perf_counter()` at my server and all works fine. Documentation says:

> While this function normally returns non-decreasing values, it can
>   return a lower value than a previous call if the system clock has been
>   set back between the two calls.

But I want to know: why it takes only few seconds to get error in my Debian server and why time difference is always about 50.85 seconds (last 3 runs: 50.84628367424011, 50.84458661079407, 50.84599566459656)?

Comment: This is not reproducible for me.

Comment: `time.time()` measures *wall clock time*. It is not guaranteed to always move forward, especially if you're synchronizing your computer's clock with an external source (e.g. using NTP).

Comment: @DanielPryden, I understand this. But I trying to understand why in my situation (Debian server) time moves back so often

Comment: Can you reproduce without using Python (e.g. using the `date` command)? I suspect you just have a bad hardware clock and NTP keeps needing to reset it. (Is the machine in question perhaps a virtual machine?)

Comment: @DanielPryden yes, same things with date. This is cheap VPS server. Looks like clock is really works wrong and get fixed every minute.